# Amazon CloudFront buffering while streaming video to Roku

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, buffer

I'm looking for help on trying to troubleshoot a buffering issue using Amazon's CloudFront service.  I've set up an S3 bucket and have it associated with a CloudFront service.  I use the service to stream videos to a public channel I developed on the Roku box.  I've been doing this since June.

Recently, I've noticed that some of the videos buffer constantly.  I can't pinpoint a reason why some do and some don't.  I've posted on the AWS and Roku forums, but, no response so far.  If anyone knows of a method to troubleshoot this performance issue, I'd be all ears.  I did try using the AWS bucket logging, but, wasn't sure what I should be looking for.

**EDIT**: From Capture logs...first is from a user, second from me.

```
2017-11-02  23:25:57    JAX1    84982   xx.xxx.32.124   GET xxx.cloudfront.net  /regattas/club/2016_Master_Nationals_Riverfront_Club_A4__Heat_2_HD.mp4  206 -   Roku/DVP-7.70%2520(087.70E04142A)   -   -   Hit kWs3_MhCRPjjbgg1PNn-4dTWa7KgCWtczsZs6O8nflyQLxFvuPK2iQ==    xxx.cloudfront.net  http    205 0.001   -   -   -   Hit HTTP/1.1
2017-11-02  23:25:56    JAX1    1520400 xx.xxx.32.124   GET xxx.cloudfront.net  /regattas/club/2016_Master_Nationals_Riverfront_Club_A4__Heat_2_HD.mp4  200 -   Roku/DVP-7.70%2520(087.70E04142A)   -   -   Error   UVOgLi06vlRmFT3Pj9Bw5l5rp1ZDJIuBl72IJYDNeLSbGib1siwdpw==    xxx.cloudfront.net  http    180 2.035   -   -   -   Hit HTTP/1.1
2017-11-02  23:25:56    JAX1    85628   xx.xxx.32.124   GET xxx.cloudfront.net  /regattas/club/2016_Master_Nationals_Riverfront_Club_A4__Heat_2_HD.mp4  206 -   Roku/DVP-7.70%2520(087.70E04142A)   -   -   Miss    LpWTXnQLQ1IUQQLe9-PSoT746pfi--nrKBxgm_ikkPft0_QzVdqC_Q==    xxx.cloudfront.net  http    205 2.050   -   -   -   Miss    HTTP/1.1
2017-11-02  23:25:57    JAX1    1025641 xx.xxx.32.124   GET xxx.cloudfront.net  /regattas/club/2016_Master_Nationals_Riverfront_Club_A4__Heat_2_HD.mp4  200 -   Roku/DVP-7.70%2520(087.70E04142A)   -   -   Error   VErphxx-KF-v1aAZK6WMW98FuM5cD1G0wm4lb_Zsx_GkbgZB2jWKHQ==    xxx.cloudfront.net  http    180 0.383   -   -   -   Hit HTTP/1.1
2017-11-02  23:28:49    MSP50   1048352 xx.xxx.32.124   GET xxx.cloudfront.net  /regattas/club/2016_Master_Nationals_Riverfront_Club_A4__Heat_2_HD.mp4  200 -   Roku/DVP-7.70%2520(087.70E04142A)   -   -   Error   0o3N4njSi3i_OqDeo-ARuZEoZQu3GqhE5_RLm9Yp05G-mwaMS_IpBA==    xxx.cloudfront.net  http    180 1.147   -   -   -   Miss    HTTP/1.1
2017-11-02  23:28:47    JAX1    48060143    xx.xxx.32.124   GET xxx.cloudfront.net  /regattas/club/2016_Master_Nationals_Riverfront_Club_A4__Heat_2_HD.mp4  200 -   Roku/DVP-7.70%2520(087.70E04142A)   -   -   Error   ZOA3ysvVKazSfhOJF9d5kiZUs80omOB9Ly3CyMC27EVtRSMVds1Y4g==    xxx.cloudfront.net  http    180 174.101 -   -   -   Miss    HTTP/1.1
2017-11-02  23:30:10    MSP50   1970009 xx.xxx.32.124   GET xxx.cloudfront.net  /regattas/club/2016_Master_Nationals_Riverfront_Club_A4__Heat_2_HD.mp4  206 -   Roku/DVP-7.70%2520(087.70E04142A)   -   -   Error   BSPf964lVszjaJ9NqqrjeD0L8uYTtXf5WA09nRJ4sdFjaAliF8IVOw==    xxx.cloudfront.net  http    204 81.618  -   -   -   Miss    HTTP/1.1

2017-11-03  20:27:19    JFK1    946020  xx.xxx.228.223  GET xxxxx.cloudfront.net    /misc/Roku_Channel_Help.mp4 200 -   Roku/DVP-8.0%2520(298.00E04108A)    -   -   Error   PK2uDUrw7Y_sUgwzFYLtc3LaWcFngofD1Hd8cFcGdRHg52AL6-ogcQ==    xxxxx.cloudfront.net    http    136 0.074   -   -   -   Hit HTTP/1.1
2017-11-03  20:27:19    JFK1    941328  xx.xxx.228.223  GET xxxxx.cloudfront.net    /misc/Roku_Channel_Help.mp4 206 -   Roku/DVP-8.0%2520(298.00E04108A)    -   -   Error   E1iykDnNjVgPL8_4c0XcIu5IJmS7v1fe5Lf3xyPR5WFciBExF7ExvA==    xxxxx.cloudfront.net    http    157 0.040   -   -   -   Hit HTTP/1.1
2017-11-03  20:29:01    JFK1    49857208    xx.xxx.228.223  GET xxxxx.cloudfront.net    /misc/Roku_Channel_Help.mp4 200 -   Roku/DVP-8.0%2520(298.00E04108A)    -   -   Hit jteprNW9dfnMeOgAB96IND8kvdkUOI3MinEcWWOjJ4gPD7L4Ee3MgQ==    xxxxx.cloudfront.net    http    136 102.339 -   -   -   Hit HTTP/1.1
2017-11-03  20:29:22    JFK1    946078  xx.xxx.228.223  GET xxxxx.cloudfront.net    /misc/Roku_Channel_Help.mp4 206 -   Roku/DVP-8.0%2520(298.00E04108A)    -   -   Error   VfGjokSp5cCVkOEgRgXPtlhPHI43TbB3syfHP2Zvta_jT4KfEhQLqA==    xxxxx.cloudfront.net    http    156 122.885 -   -   -   Hit HTTP/1.1
2017-11-03  20:34:10    JFK5    384794  xx.xxx.228.223  GET xxxxx.cloudfront.net    /misc/Roku_Channel_Help.mp4 206 -   Roku/DVP-8.0%2520(298.00E04108A)    -   -   Error   jesajhZRE1O3IUKbgq0Us7qlvJXRTsjbZyFxfsnaXIDT_We9vEUZAA==    xxxxx.cloudfront.net    http    157 0.118   -   -   -   Miss    HTTP/1.1
2017-11-03  20:34:10    JFK5    982211  xx.xxx.228.223  GET xxxxx.cloudfront.net    /misc/Roku_Channel_Help.mp4 200 -   Roku/DVP-8.0%2520(298.00E04108A)    -   -   Error   OsJceDTgVJPEd6gz4CKp9XCpUOpc__EwS7CfRhnwOjPaSSLIcu3xUg==    xxxxx.cloudfront.net    http    136 0.316   -   -   -   Miss    HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: You need to capture logs for *both* the bucket and for CloudFront, observe both and compare them to each other.  You need to know whether the Roku is making complete requests or `Range` requests and whether they are going back to S3 or being served from the CloudFront cache, and which CloudFront edge locations are involved.  There is a great deal of information to be learned from the logs, and until you have a grasp of that, it will be difficult for anyone to speculate about the possible nature of the problem.  A local packet trace would also be valuable.

Comment: Thanks. I have enabled logging for both the bucket and cf. I'll report back.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  I've captured some S3 and CF log files.  On thing that jumps out at me from the CF logs, is that I get a 2xx status code with a 'x-edge-result-type' = ERROR.  Does that seem plausible?  Additionally, yesterday, most videos would buffer.  Today, they seem fine.  ISP problem?

Comment: It sounds like it could be exactly that.  2XX + ERROR suggests that the request succeeded initially but something went wrong before the last byte left the edge.  Can you include some log lines with only the sensitive bits redacted?  Notice that the edge identifier is there, in XXXN or XXXNN format (e.g. `IAD6`).  Were the problems limited to one edge or multiple edges in the same locale or global?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Edited question with posted logs.  Problem appears in more than one edge.

Comment: Everything between the S3 and CloudFront seems to have been okay.  It's interesting that your user accessed edges in both Florida and Minnesota -- that's quite a geographic split, but *might* represent CloudFront trying to route traffic away from a problem.  Yours both went to edges in NYC.  Unfortunately, there's another factor to consider, which is what logs look like when things are working correctly.  Here, it appears that the connection may be lost or the Roku abandons it (which *might* be normal in some cases). Does the Roku expose any playback debugging tools?